# Can (and should) wifi internet be considered a force?

Tags: forces, definition, interactions, computer, technology

I've recently been using my wifi internet, for the last few years and have been enjoying it very much. I am able to communicate with my family across the globe in mere seconds, it's obviously a marvel of modern science.

However, I have been reminiscing about my school days, specifically my physics lectures. We learned that a force is something that acts upon something else and results in a physical reaction. Back then I took this at face value but recently I have wondered if the wifi internet is a force. It must priduce some physical reaction in order for me to see the website pages it loads onto my computer.

So I ask this, is wifi internet a force? Thank you.

I tried to add the tag "internet" to this question but I was not allowed!!

Answer (score 7):

It all depends on what you mean by "force". In the physical sciences, "force" has a defined meaning. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force) defines force as "a force is an influence that can change the motion of an object". In other words, a force can change the speed or momentum of an object. Changing the momentum means that force imparts an acceleration to an object, as per Newton's law $$ F=ma$$

Using that definition, the internet is **not** a force. WiFi is not either, unless you use some mechanism to convert the microwave energy of the WiFi signal into a physical force.

Force is measured in Newtons ($N$) or, in the US and Liberia, in Pounds-force ($lb$).

Beyond science, "force" can mean many things, e.g.

```
   force of your personality   
   force of your argument   
   moral strength   
   military strength
```

The internet can indeed be a "force" this way. But then, so can many parts of the internet like social media, or even search engines. They can be both a force for good, and a force for bad. But, they are not physical forces.

Apart from the example I gave above, I cannot see how WiFi can be considered a force. It is a microwave signal, and a set of protocols designed to manage that signal. It's a method to connect your device to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Your lecturer was incorrect. That would be an adequate definition of force in the colloquial, nonscientific sense only.

Physical force, most strictly, is that vector quantity whose vector sum corresponds to the distance of displacement of an ideal spring from equilibrium. Slightly less strictly, it is that quantity whose vector sum is the rate of change of momentum with respect to time and the integrand with distance of mechanical work.

None of these definitions fits wifi or the internet. Computers communicate using electromagnetic force, but the force is what the signal does, not the signal itself, and certainly not the machinery that creates and responds to the signal. Similarly, coffee can warm your mouth, which is also an electromagnetic force interaction, but neither the heat nor the coffee is a force.